# Changing my own tags to data from XML

Tags: java, xml

I have a text editor where user can put text like this:

> [[PAYMENTS_N]] You have to pay [[amount]]$ before [[date]].[[/PAYMENTS_N]]
>   [[PAYMENTS_Z]] You didn't pay [[debt]]$ on time: [[ddate]].[[/PAYMENTS_Z]]

And there are XML files that look like this:

```
<DATA_NZ><USER><ID>12345</ID><COMP_NZ><COMP>
<STATUS>Z</STATUS>
<AMOUNT_NZ>128.01</AMOUNT_NZ>
<DATE_NZ>28.05.2015</DATE_NZ>

<STATUS>N</STATUS>
<AMOUNT_NZ>12.32</AMOUNT_NZ>
<DATE_NZ>21.09.2015</DATE_NZ>

<STATUS>N</STATUS>
<AMOUNT_NZ>12.32</AMOUNT_NZ>
<DATE_NZ>20.10.2015</DATE_NZ>
</COMP></COMP_NZ></USER></DATA_NZ>
```

Now I want to change the text from editor into something like this:

> Remember about your next payments: 
>   You have to pay 12.32$ before 21.09.2015. 
>   You have to pay 12.32$ before 20.10.2015.
>
> You didn't pay 128.01$ on time: 28.05.2015.

And I have this code:

```
public void parseTags(String content) {
    String nOpenTag, nCloseTag;
    String zOpenTag, zCloseTag;
    String dnTag, knTag, dzTag, kzTag;

    nOpenTag = "[[PAYMENTS_N]]";
    nCloseTag = "[[/PAYMENTS_N]]";

    zOpenTag = "[[PAYMENTS_Z]]";
    zCloseTag = "[[/PAYMENTS_Z]]";

    dnTag = "[[amount]]";
    knTag = "[[date]]";
    dzTag = "[[debt]]";
    kzTag = "[[ddate]]";

    String textToExtract = "";
    String textToExtract = "";
    String textToReplace = "";
    String parsedContent = content;//; = content;
    if (content.contains(nOpenTag) || content.contains(zOpenTag)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getXMLContainer("SZUK_XM4.XML").getUsers().size(); i++) {
            if (getXMLContainer("SZUK_XM4.XML").getUsers().get(i) != null) { //
                contact = consentService.findByContactTypeAndIdNumber(ContactType.EMAIL, getXMLContainer("SZUK_XM4.XML").getUsers().get(i).getIdNumber());
                payments = getXMLContainer("SZUK_XM4.XML").getUsers().get(i).getPaymentContainer().getPayments();
                if (contact.size() > 0) {
                    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
                    StringBuilder strB2 = new StringBuilder();
                    String textToReplace;
                    for (int c = 0; c < contact.size(); c++) {
                        strB.setLength(0);
                        for (int p = 0; p < payments.size(); p++) {
                            if (payments.get(p).getStatus().contains("N")) {
                                textToExtract = content.substring(content.indexOf(nOpenTag) + nOpenTag.length(), content.indexOf(nCloseTag));
                                textToReplace = textToExtract.replace(dnTag, "Day " + payments.get(p).getPaymentDate());
                                textToReplace = textToReplace.replace(knTag, "Amount " + payments.get(p).getPaymentAmount());
                                strB.append(textToReplace);
                                parsedContent = content.replace(textToExtract, strB.toString());
                            }

                            if (payments.get(p).getStatus().contains("Z")) {
                                textToExtract = parsedContent.substring(parsedContent.indexOf(zOpenTag) + zOpenTag.length(), parsedContent.indexOf(zCloseTag));
                                textToReplace = textToExtract.replace(dzTag, "Day " + payments.get(p).getPaymentDate());
                                textToReplace = textToReplace.replace(kzTag, "Amount " + payments.get(p).getPaymentAmount());
                                strB2.append(textToReplace);
                                parsedContent = parsedContent.replace(textToExtract, strB2.toString());
                            }
                        }

                        mailService.sendTemplateMail(contact.get(c).getContact(), parsedContent);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to find in the database user with given ID from XML. 
If user exists then it reads all the data between  and replaces [[TAGS]] from the text editor. After everything's done, it should send an email with replaced text.

The problem is that the text it sends isn't correctly replaced. It gives

> Remember about your next payments: You have to pay 12.32$ before
>   21.09.2015. You have to pay 12.32$ before 20.10.2015.
>
> You didn't pay [[debt]]$ on time: [[ddate]].

See the difference in the last line?

I'm using JAXB to read XML, if it matters.

Hope you can help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
parsedContent = content.replace(textToExtract, strB.toString());
```

with:

```
parsedContent = parsedContent.replace(textToExtract, strB.toString());
```